# name 'conn' is not defined: NameError

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to store my aws iot mqtt messages into my postgresql. To do so, I have already connected my local posrtgresql to the amazon RDS instance. Now, I need to create a connection between amazon lambda calculus and then send the data to the postgresql database. But whenever, I am testing my lambda calculus, it was giving me "name 'conn' is not defined: NameError" error. Here, is my python code in aws lambda. I have also included the psycopg2 library to my project.

```
import sys
import logging
import rds_config
import psycopg2
#rds settings
rds_host  = "myhost"
name = "username"
password = "username_password"
db_name = "dbname"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=rds_host, user=name, password=password, 
           dbname=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except:
     logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to postgreSQL 
          instance.")

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS postgreSQL instance succeeded")
def handler(event, context):
"""
This function fetches content from postgreSQL RDS instance
"""
item_count = 0
with conn.cursor() as cur: 
    cur.execute('insert into awsiotdata (serialnumber, dateandtime, clicktype, batteryvoltage) values(serialNumber, datetime.datetime.utcnow(), clickType, batteryVoltage)')
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("select * from awsiotdata")
    for row in cur:
        item_count += 1
        logger.info(row)
        #print(row)


return "Added %d items from RDS PostgreSQL table" %(item_count)
```

Comment: You need to run the lambda function in a VPC / make the RDS publicly accessible. You should go with the first option. Also, ensure that the right security groups are assigned to the resources. Public RDS is not recommended.

Comment: For the testing purpose, my RDS is publicly accessible.

Comment: What is your security group rules looks like?

Comment: I am using the default security groups rules from the dropdown. @SudharsanSivasankaran

Comment: Do you RDS restricted to a IP? The inbound rule should be 0.0.0.0/0 for lambda to access, or else you would need put lambda inside a VPC.

Comment: My RDS is publicly accessible right now. I just want to create a connection and insert data into my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hiding a true error message. Exception handling patter for Python looks like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=rds_host,
                            user=name,
                            password=password,
                            database=db_name)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This way you will see the real error message:

> invalid dsn: invalid connection option "passwd"

**Edit #1:**

"Timeout" means that lambda can't connect because of "Security group rules" for RDS instance. Please keep in mind that even  public RDS instance by default have inbound restriction by IP (i.e. it is posible to connect from PC but it is imposible to connect from AWS Lambda).

[image: RDS wizard]
[image: RDS instance options]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have used your answer to check the error. Now, it is giving me "Task timed out after 3.00 seconds" error message. I am not understanding the reason behind it. @Ovidijus

Comment: I did the same thing what you showed in the image. But still, the same error is showing.

Comment: I mean that "CIDR/IP-inbound" should be "0.0.0.0/0".

Other possible solutions could be:

1) increase Lambda "Timeout" in "Basic settings";

2) make Lambda structure like in this example: https://gist.github.com/A1O/55b755c3b4ebc667372a209a90bc4503

3) chek AWS CoudWatch logs for more information about error;

4) provide more information about code, frameworks, errors.

Comment: Thanks mate! My lambda connection is connected to my database and see the data from the database. I have added all the subnet groups and then it works! The present problem is when I am clicking my iot button, it is showing the mqtt message in the aws console but not stored in my database. I might need to change my lambda execution role for that. In my execution role, I have attached 4 policies which are AWSLambdaIoTButtonExecutionRole,LambdaBasicExecutionRole, LambdaVPCExecutionRole,LambdaRole. But I cannot store the message in my database. Can you tell me where am I doing wrong? @Ovidijus

Comment: @Mahbub: 1) check CloudWatch logs for lambda; 2) follow  the process of setting up your AWS IoT button at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-button-quickstart.html#next-steps

Comment: Voila! It is working now. Thanks for your instructions @Ovidijus. I will write the answer precisely soon.